# Vue + typescript - calling a variable declared in Data() in a method

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have just started using vue3 with typescript, I am coming from vue2 with js and i can't understand how to fix an IDE error (the code itself works, but probably is not 100% correct)

so, this is the code

```
export default {
  name: 'Sidebar',
  data() {
    return {
      menu: { name: 'Menu', icon: MenuIcon },
      navigation: [
        { id: 0, name: 'Home', icon: HomeIcon, path: '/', count:0, current: true },
        { id: 1, name: 'Users', icon: UsersIcon, path: '/about', count: 3, current: false },
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    makeCurrent: function(item: navItem) {
      this.navigation.forEach((nav: { current: boolean; id: any; }) => {
        nav.current = nav.id === item.id;
      })
    }
  }
}
```

the IDE highlights "navigation" in `this.navigation.forEach(...`
and gives the following error

TS2339: Property 'navigation' does not exist on type '{ makeCurrent: (item: navItem) => void; }'

Comment: Options API wasn't designed to provide good TS support, this one of reasons for composition API to exist. If you need to use options, at least use defineComponent helper. "the IDE highlights" - this may be specific to IDE because it has a different toolchain, it's incorrect to ask the question in general until it's confirmed that the TS error occurs in both IDE and build

Comment: https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#definecomponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to the TS inference in a .vue component is to wrap the

```
export default { ...options }
```

In the `defineComponent` method

So something like this:

```
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Sidebar',
  data() {
    return {
      menu: { name: 'Menu', icon: MenuIcon },
      navigation: [
        { id: 0, name: 'Home', icon: HomeIcon, path: '/', count:0, current: true },
        { id: 1, name: 'Users', icon: UsersIcon, path: '/about', count: 3, current: false },
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    makeCurrent: function(item: navItem) {
      this.navigation.forEach((nav: { current: boolean; id: any; }) => {
        nav.current = nav.id === item.id;
      })
    }
  }
});
```

PS
You can also use the `defineComponent` method **in vue.js 2** using the
https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api plugin